# Can I open UNIX POSIX ports from Python?

Tags: python

Can I open UNIX POSIX ports from Python 2.7 ( I don't need IP port, just UNIX POSIX) ? Does anybody have experience with this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are talking about Unix domain sockets (I'm not sure what you mean by "UNIX POSIX port"... IP sockets have ports, Unix sockets don't).  The standard system calls are available through a thin wrapper.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind("/path/to/socket")
s.listen(100)
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    do_something(conn, addr)
```

Or for connecting to an existing Unix socket...

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect("/path/to/socket")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(path)
```